# Is "go down a storm" similar to "go down well"?

Tags: prepositions, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

Something goes down a storm with somebody.

Something goes down well with somebody.

Are they the same in the meaning?

Or do they differ? such as one is formal and the other is informal?

BBC
English we speak
[Source link](https://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/language/theenglishwespeak/2012/12/130101_tews_104_go_down_a_storm.shtml)

Comment: What is the source please?

Comment: Hi! I add the source. Appreciate your asking.

Comment: I've read the source material, which explains the meaning in context. It's not an expression that I've ever come across. However, I see it listed on several sites and clearly others are familiar with it. https://www.lexico.com/synonyms/go_down_well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never heard of the phrase "goes down a storm" before, but after reading the definition from the article you linked, it looks like they have similar meanings. However "goes down a storm" is definitely a more informal phrase to use than "goes down well". Also, "goes down a storm" appears to be a British phrase, so if you were to say it to somebody living in the US, they would most likely not know what it means.

Comment: How do you think about "go down a bomb" which I read in OLD, This dictionary says that is used in North American English. https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/bomb_1#bomb_idmg_2

Comment: @StatsCruncher That dictionary says *go down a bomb* is British, not North American: *go down a bomb | go (like) a bomb  (British English) to be very successful*  I have never heard the expression in the US.

Comment: Er. How come I was such careless? Thanks to @stangdon for your positive response based on experience in the US. I believe that using these informal expressions need care as well.